# Link_to with a triple nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just beginning to learn how to program and, as practice, am trying to put together a generic facebook-like program. However, when I put in the code provided below, I keep getting the following error:

No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil, :user_id=>"4"} missing required keys: [:post_id]

**Route**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<% @user.posts.each do |p| %>     
<ul><b><%= p.id%></b></ul>
<ul><b><%= p.post%></b></ul>
<ul><em><%= p.created_at%></em></ul> 
<ul><%= link_to "Delete Post", [p.user, p], method: :delete %> </ul>
<ul><%= link_to "Comment", new_user_post_comment_path(@user, p.id) %> </ul>
<%end%>
```

**Controller**

```
def show
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id)]
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end
```

I've tried a number of different things in the link_to section with the "p.id"; which I think is probably giving me the issue; however, nothing seems to work. I've tried a number of other things that I've read about how to deal with linking with triple nested routes; however, nothing has worked so far.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, among all user's comments, there is a comment with `post_id = nil`. Check all `@user.comments` for post_id

Answer (score 0):

Your error is this:

> No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments",
>   :post_id=>nil, :user_id=>"4"} missing required keys: [:post_id]

The error means you're not sending the `post_id` parameter, which is required for nested routes. The whole point of a *nested* route is that you get various resources for `parent` resources. This means you cannot find the child resources without specifying the parent ones

To fix this, I would recommend the following:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Post", user_post_path(p.user, p), method: :delete %>
<%= link_to "Comment", new_user_post_comment_path(@user, p) %>
```

The tricky part is I don't know which of your links is causing the error

---

You also have a typo in your controller: `Post.find(params[:post_id])`